# HA Proxy Prioritized Connections

Tags: proxy, haproxy, high-availability

I am using HAProxy and I have been trying to set it up to work a certain way.
I want it so that if server 11.111.11.110 connects then it will always hit ABC_server01 unless that server is offline.

However this is how I have it currently written using weights:

```
acl the_workstation src 11.111.11.110
use_backend ABC if the_workstation

backend ABC
  server ABC_server01 22.222.22.220:443 weight 255 maxconn 512 check
  server ABC_server02 33.333.33.333:443 weight 1 maxconn 512 check
  server ABC_server03 44.444.44.444:443 weight 1 maxconn 512 check
```

With what is written up top I believe that in 257 connection attempts 2 will not use ABC_server01.

I looked into if loops and timeouts however I was not able to come up with a working solution. 
https://www.haproxy.org/coding-style.html
http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/doc/configuration.txt

Does anyone know a simple way to make it prioritize connection to a server then use the other remaining servers if the connection fais?

This is the current version of HA Proxy I am using "HA-Proxy version 1.5.18 2016/05/10"

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution we altered the code to look like this:

```
acl the_workstation src 11.111.11.110
use_backend ABC if the_workstation

backend ABC
  server ABC_server01 22.222.22.220:443 weight 255 maxconn 512 check
  server ABC_server02 33.333.33.333:443 weight 1 maxconn 512 check backup
  server ABC_server03 44.444.44.444:443 weight 1 maxconn 512 check backup
```

By adding backup it will only hit those servers if the first is offline.